# Overflowing signed/unsigned assignments and its results

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed, integer-overflow

I'm reading a Stroustrup's book "The C++ Programming Language 4th edition" and have three questions regarding overflowing assignments (particularily to signed/unsigned chars, as the book exemplifies). Firstly, according to standard 5/4 paragraph:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, **the behavior is undefined**.

(Except when a destination variable is unsigned - the result is clearly defined in such case). But does this definition also pertain to assignments?

Because in my opinion there are many contrary statements in the book, all in chapter 6. The first one corresponds to the aforementioned paragraph, however the following comments doesn't:

> Variables of the three `char` types can be freely assigned to each
>   other. However, assigning a too large value to a `signed char` is still
>   undefined. For example:
>
> ```
> void g(char c, signed char sc, unsigned char uc)
> {
>     c = 255; //implementation-defined if plain chars are signed and have 8 bits
>     c = sc; //OK
>     c = uc; //implementation-defined if plain chars are signed and if uc's value is too large
>     sc = uc; //implementation-defined if uc's value is too large
>     uc = sc; //OK: conversion to unsigned
>     sc = c; //implementation-defined if plain chars are unsigned and if c's value is too large
>     uc = c; //OK: conversion to unsigned
> }
> ```

**First question**: since assigning a too large value is UB, then why comments say it's implementation-defined?

Next we have the following example:

> To be concrete, assume that a `char` is 8 bits:
>
> ```
> signed char sc = -160;
> unsigned char uc = sc; //uc == 116 (because 256-160==116)
> cout << uc; //print 't'
> ```

**Second question**: apart from the fact that the first assignment is supposedly UB, what formula exactly has the author used in order to come up with 116? In my test, `uc` got the value of 96.

And the last quote:

> An integer can be converted to another integer type. If the
>   destination is `signed`, the value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is
>   implementation-defined:
>
> `signed char sc = 1023; //implementation-defined`
>
> Plausible results are 127 and -1.

**Third question**: again, apart from the fact that this contrary to what have been said earlier about UB, why possible results are 127 and -1? I guess it has something to do with one's and two's complement, but what are the precise formulas used?

Comment: Could you, please, provide the chapter with the above mentioned text for one to check this in PDF version.

Comment: @SChepurin it's chapter 6.

Comment: And section number? I don't believe the book changed dramatically from third edition, since there ch. 6 is *Expressions and Statements*.

Comment: @SChepurin It's actually 6.2.3.1 (chapter 6 - Types and Declarations) and 10.5.2.1 (chapter 10 - Expressions).

Comment: Third Edition - Chapter 4 *Types and Declarations* and nothing similar to what you ask about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Implementation defined is "a class of UB" - in other words, it's still UB, it's just that the implementation is responsible for explaining how it works, rather than "you can't at all rely on this operation". So, the compiler is still allowed to explode your computer if you assign out-of-range `char` values. But the implementation can also define that "it chops it to the 8-bit equivalent value".

2) 256 - 160 = 96 on my calculator. I bet it is on yours as well. Maybe the author had a different calculator? Or it's one of those things that got changed last minute from -150 to -160, it forgot to change the end result.

3) Since it's "implementation defined", it could end up being almost anything. Since the value is 0x3ff in hex, we can imagine either 0xff or 0x7f as plausible values, depending on how the implementation decides to do that. I expect MOST compilers will use the 0xff value.

Comment: 2) OK, but why subtracting from 256? 3) Why 0x7f?

Comment: 2) Because that's what happens when you "chop" a number off. 3) Because that's a "maximum positive number that the type can hold" - in other words, the value you get if you don't change it's sign in a signed value. One could imagine that this is a reasonable response to "too large a value", just as much as getting `-1`... It is after all "allowed" to be either. It's unlikely to be 124 or 75, but technically, those are also valid, if the implementer decided to document it that way.