# Programming principles and practice 2nd ed. signed char overflow

Tags: c++, char

I've finished C++ primer 5th edition and now I'm reading C++ programming principles and practice 2nd edition by Strostrup. However the author seems to depend on some UBs in many cases like this one:

> ```
>  int x = 2.9;
>  char c = 1066;
> ```
>
> Here `x` will get the value `2` rather than `2.9` , because `x` is an `int` and `int`s don’t have values that are fractions of an integer, just whole integers (obviously). Similarly, if we use the common ASCII character set, `c` will get the value `42` (representing
> the character `*` ), rather than `1066`, because there is no `char` with the value `1066` in that character set.

But `char x = 1066;` is overflowing a `signed char` so the behavior is undefined and I'm not sure about what he is saying: it produces `*` because a UB can mean anything as I guess thus we don't depend or even guess the results. So what do you think? Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569566/why-256-for-a-signed-char-is-undefined-in-c

Comment: `char x = 1066;` performs a _narrowing conversion_, before the value is assigned to a `char`.  This is an implementation-defined behavior (not UB), and does not cause the `char` to overflow.

Comment: An overflow is when the result of an operation can't be represented in the type. This is not an overflow, but a narrowing conversion.

Comment: related (duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976878/overflowing-signed-unsigned-assignments-and-its-results

Comment: @DrewDormann No longer implementation defined since C++20. The behaviour is defined in the standard now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But char x = 1066; is overflowing a signed char so the behavior is undefined

That's not true.

Overflow happens as a result of an arithmetic operation. What happens here is conversion. Converting an unrepresentable integer to another integer type does not have undefined behaviour even if the type is signed.

P.S. `char` is not `signed char`. They are distinct types. It's implementation defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: So it is not UB in assignments too: `c = 2048; // assignment`? Give me an example of UB doing so (arithmetic).

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Assignment isn't UB, same as initialisation. This is UB: `INT_MAX + 1`

Comment: Ah ok! so  `char c; c = 5000;` is not a UB too but `char c = 127; ++c;` is UB right?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa That can be UB, on the condition that `127 == CHAR_MAX`